# matlab: multiplication inside cellfun

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Hi I have the following cellfun operation:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

where u and r are vectors. I want to multiply the result of the cross product by a scalar called I, but it has to inside the summation. could I simply do:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(I.*cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Would this work?

Actually just tried it and getting:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> cellcross>@(x)nansum(mag.*cross(u{1},x)) at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(mag.*cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);

Error in ==> cellcross at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(mag.*cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

any suggestions?

update:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(bsxfun(@times, mag(:),cross(u{1},x))),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on the long discussion below, I now have a grasp on your problem. 
For future reference: providing a bit more context/detail can prevent such discussions.

Anyway, try this:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(...
    mag.* subsref(cross(u{1},x), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {':',':',3})) ),...
    r, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it does what you ask.

Comment: HI Rody - sorry for the late reply - guess we are in different time zonez :) 

>> size(magI)

ans =

     9     9

Comment: @brucezepplin ah well there you go; it's not a scalar :) The output of `cross` is Nx3, and obviously, you cannot multiply a 9x9 matrix with a Nx3 matrix element-wise :)

Comment: how about taking the z dimension scalar field and multiplying by magI? can that be done within the cellfun operation? and more precisely inside the nansum function.

Comment: @brucezepplin you mean like `mag .* cross(...)(:,3)`? No -- `mag` is still 9x9...I'm not sure anymore what you're trying to get to; could you perhaps post a bit more context and rephrase your question?

Comment: @brucezepplin I guess you should also have a look at `help bsxfun`

Comment: every time the cross product is performed, I end up with a 3 dim vector field. I want to take the z dimension of that vector field (size 9 9) and multiply by magI (size 9 9).

Comment: @brucezepplin So you're saying, `size(cross(u{1},x)) = [9 9 3]` ?

Comment: well techincally no it's 81 3, but I reshape that after the cellfun operation to an object size [9 9 3]

Comment: @brucezepplin see my edit. During my edit you posted your previous comment, so based on that: why not just do `bsxfun(@times, mag(:), cross(...))` without reshaping? `mag(:)` will be a 81x1 vector, and without reshaping, the `cross(...)` will be 81x3 -- much simpler than 3D arrays...

Comment: thanks Rody - please see my edited post for the version I am now using based on your suggestion. does it look right. I am now getting no error.

Comment: @brucezepplin it looks right, but only you can verify whether it actually IS right :P